# "IsADirectoryError" Django

Tags: python, django

при разработке  сайта на Django,я столкнулся с ошибкой
на домашней странице:

```
    IsADirectoryError at /catalog/
[Errno 21] Is a directory: '/home/fedor/Project/django/fourm/fourm/templates'
```

содержимое site/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import include
from django.urls import path
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin



urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

urlpatterns += [
     path('catalog/', include('catalog.urls')),
]
urlpatterns += [
    path('', RedirectView.as_view(url='/catalog/', permanent=True)),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

'

содержимое catalog/urls.py:

```
    from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

содержимое apps.py :

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class CatalogConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'catalog'
```

содержимое settings.py:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'catalog.apps.CatalogConfig',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'fourm.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR)],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'fourm.wsgi.application'


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}



AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

SETTINGS_PATH = os.path.normpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
# Find templates in the same folder as settings.py.
#TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
#    os.path.join(SETTINGS_PATH, 'templates'),
#)
#
TEMPLATE_DIRS = [
    '/home/fedor/Project/django/fourm/templates'
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

содержимое  viwes.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import  Author
def index(request):

   num_authors=Author.objects.count() 
   return render(request, 'fourm/templates/', context={'num_authors':num_authors})
```

папка проекта:

```
Site/
  catalog/
     admin.py
     appps.py
     models.py
     tests.py
     urls.py
     viwes.py
  site/
     asgi.py
     settings.py
     urls.py
     wsgi.py
     teamplates/
        index.html
```

как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Предоставьте больше данных - структуру проекта (текстом), `catalog.urls`, представления, все места, где используется `templates`

Comment: добавил в вопрос

Comment: `views.py` тоже

Comment: `teamplates/` - тут опечатка

Comment: опечатка вопросе,viwes.py добавил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def index(request):

   num_authors=Author.objects.count() 
   return render(request, 'fourm/templates/', context={'num_authors':num_authors})
```

`'fourm/templates/'` - это директория, укажите файл шаблона относительно папки `templates`, например, `'index.html'`